# Rewrite application from VB to C++ and get error 0070

Tags: vb.net, com, c++-cli

I am rewriting the client application for COM from VB to C ++:

VB

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim proxy As Person
Set proxy = New Person
proxy.FirstName = "Maxim"
proxy.LastName = "Donax"
proxy.Persist ("C:\myFile.xml")
End Sub
```

C++

```
#import "COM.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, no_namespace, named_guids
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Person per; // error 0070
    per.FirstName = "Maxim"; // error 3365
    per.LastName = "Donax";// error 3365
    per.Persist(" C:\myFile.xml ");// error 3365
}
```

I get an error E0070:Incomplete type not allowed, which itself create errors 3365: Incomplete type not allowed of class "Person" in next strings

I understand what I am doing wrong, but I cannot find the right solution. Help please.

COM.tlb:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace COM
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class Person : System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent, IPerson
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool IsMale { get; set; }
        public void Persist(string FilePath)
        {
            StreamWriter oFile = new StreamWriter(FilePath);
            XmlSerializer oXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
            oXmlSerializer.Serialize(oFile, this);
            oFile.Flush();
            oFile.Close();
        }
        static public Person Retrieve(string FilePath)
        {
            StreamReader oFile = new StreamReader(FilePath);
            XmlSerializer oXmlSerilizer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
            Person oPerson = oXmlSerilizer.Deserialize(oFile) as Person;
            return oPerson;

        }
    }
}
```

IPerson.cs

```
using System;
namespace COM
{
    public interface IPerson
    {
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        bool IsMale { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }

        void Persist(string FilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is IPerson defined in C#?

Comment: @SimonMourier Added IPerson.cs, you wanted to see it, right?

Comment: In C++, you don't declare an instance of `Person`, you declare a pointer to it.  `#import` will make a bunch of convenience typedefs for `_com_ptr_t` smart pointers.  You should be declaring something like a `PersonPtr`.  I don't remember the ceremony for creating a new `Person` object, but you may find a member of `_com_ptr_t` that will do it for you.  Because it's a pointer (or pointer-like object) you will access the members using `->` rather than `.`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to learn a bit of C++ to be able to do this.

Also just have a look at the `.tlh` (and possibly `.tli`) file that was generated in the output folder by Visual Studio.

So, here is how to instantiate and call the COM object (for example using the Windows SDK tools/wrappers from comdef.h like `_bstr_t`):

```
#include <windows.h>
#import "COM.tlb" raw_interfaces_only, raw_native_types, no_namespace, named_guids

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    {
        IPersonPtr per(__uuidof(Person)); // equivalent of CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Person,..., IID_IPerson, &person)
        per->put_FirstName(_bstr_t(L"Maxim"));
        per->put_LastName(_bstr_t(L"Donax"));
        per->Persist(_bstr_t(L"c:\\myFile.xml"));
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Or a bit more simple (use convenient wrappers automagically generated):

```
#include <windows.h>
#import "COM.tlb"

using namespace COM; // your namespace, COM is probably not a good namespace name

int main()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    {
        IPersonPtr per(__uuidof(Person));
        per->PutFirstName(L"Maxim");
        per->PutLastName(L"Donax");
        per->Persist(L"c:\\myFile.xml");
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know nothing of C++; just curious. I find it confusing that the pointer variable, `IPersonPtr` begins with "I" which, to me, says pointer to the Interface but I see it points to `Person`. Is this a convention in C++?

Comment: @Mary - With COM (and in other platforms/languages), there is a convention that interfaces start with an I. The real interface is named IPerson (at C++ level, it's an abstract pure virtual class, at binary level and C level, it's a struct), and IPersonPtr is a wrapper that's built by the #import directive (you must use Visual Studio to take a look at it). In COM you only deal with interfaces but the tooling you use (here #import) can add lots of other concepts.

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried second variant, but I get unhandled exception at 0x76BCC5AF in ConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C ++ Exception: _com_error at memory address 0x0040F8F0(Add screen, but VS in Russian). How do I decipher and fix it? =)

Comment: @donax - It's probably your COM object that has issues.